# Footer at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the footer at the bottom of the page.

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <header id="main__header"> 
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="search">
          <form> 
            <input type="text"  value="Search..." /> 
          </form>
        </div>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li id="carrers"><a href="#">Carrers</a></li>
            <li id="newsletter"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section id="body__section">

        <section id="left__section" class="margin__section"> 
          <article id="news1">
            <img src="images/pic.jpg"  width="200"  height="170" alt="pic1" />
            <header> </header>
            <div>
              <p> </p> 
            </div>
          </article>

          <article id="news2">
            <img src="images/pic.jpg"  width="200"  height="170" alt="pic2" />
            <header> </header>
              <div>
                <p> </p> 
              </div>
            </article>

            <article id="news3">
              <img src="images/pic.jpg"  width="200"  height="170" alt="pic2" />
              <header> </header>
              <div>
                <p> </p> 
              </div>
            </article>

            <article id="news4">
              <img src="images/pic.jpg"  width="200"  height="170" alt="pic3" />
              <header> </header>
              <div>
                <p> </p> 
              </div>
            </article>
          </section>

          <section id="right__section" class="margin__section"> 
            <aside id="social"></aside>
            <aside  class="ad"></aside>
            <aside class="ad"></aside>
          </section>

        </section>

        <footer> </footer>

      </div>    
    </body>
  </html>
```

My style.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body, #main {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body, #main_header, nav, ul, footer {
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
} 

#main__header {
  position: relative; 
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ff532a;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 206px;
  height: 75px;
}

#search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: right;
  width: 1061px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 209px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#home {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#body__section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#left__section {
  width: 810px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#right__section {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d3d2;
}

.margin__section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}


article {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d3d2;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  height: 230px;
  width: 100%;
}

section article img {
  margin: 30px;
}

section article div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: url('images/article.jpg');
}

.border__solid {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#right__section aside {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px; 
}

#social {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #e7e8e7;
}

.ad {
  height: 377px;
  background-color: #ffffa1;    
}

footer {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #beb0ff;
}
```

The problem is that the gray footer stays in the middle under the section. I really want the footer to be at the bottom of the page, not fixed.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz2NP.jpg)

Comment: Try to add `position:absolute` to your footer

Comment: I tried many versions with absolute position... and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These changes will fix things for you:

```
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto; //changing to auto
  width: 1100px;
}

footer {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #beb0ff;
  position: relative; //changing to relative
  clear: both; //clearing previous divs
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an element with "clear: both" after the two floating sections that you have inside your container section. Then you have to remove the "height: 100%" from your container section.

So, add to your css:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Change your "#body__section" to:

```
#body__section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And add to your html, just before the end of the "body__section":

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use this CSS...

```
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 180px;
} 
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #beb0ff;
}
```

...and take the 'main element out of this rule:

```
html, body, #main {
  height: 100%;
}
```

so it becomes

```
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This makes the footer a child of `#main`, absolutely positioned at its bottom, with enough `padding-bottom` on `#main` to prevent any overlapping(180px, like the height of the footer), and a `min-height` of 100% for `#main`  to ensure the footer is also at the bottom on pages which aren't that high.